# Error with DateDif in Excel

Tags: excel

i am trying to use the DateDif function in Excel and this is an error and i had no idea why.

An example of the function that i want to calculate the number of years between the date is `

> =DATEDIF("13/4/2013","1/1/2015","Y")
>
> =DATEDIF("20/4/2013","1/1/2015","Y")
>
> =DATEDIF("29/4/2013","1/1/2015","Y")

`Then the error came up was #VALUE! for all these above examples whereas if i use

> =DATEDIF("12/4/2013","1/1/2015","Y")
>
> =DATEDIF("5/4/2013","1/1/2015","Y")

There are no errors and the function worked correctly and the result is 1

Any help ? Or maybe its just a bug ?

Comment: If so then at least in Excel maybe also in your Windows system the default date format is `mm/dd/yyyy` and not `dd/mm/yyyy` as you might think.

Comment: I tend to use e.g. DATE(2013,4,13) to avoid this. See also http://excelsemipro.com/2011/06/regional-date-formats-in-excel/

Answer (score 0):

> =DATEDIF("12/4/2013","1/1/2015","Y")

Returns `1` because whether from December 4, 2013 or April 12, 2013 there is over a year and less than two years until January 1, 2015.

Similarly for your last example where whether May 4 or April 5 makes no difference.

Your first three examples return errors because your system is not interpreting `13/4/2013`, `20/4/2013` and `29/4/2013` as dates, as are required for [DATEDIF](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/datedif.aspx). With your system set up you should see the results you were expecting from:

```
=DATEDIF("4/13/2013","1/1/2015","Y")  
=DATEDIF("4/20/2013","1/1/2015","Y")  
=DATEDIF("4/29/2013","1/1/2015","Y")
```